# How to call returned function with implicits without assigning to val

Tags: scala, implicit

Suppose I have an object like:

```
object MyObj {
  def apply(args: List[String])(implicit v: Int): Unit => Int = (_: Unit) => args.length + v
}
```

If I want to MyObj.apply, I have to do:

```
implicit val v = 5
val myObj = MyObj(List("a", "b", "c"))
myObj()
```

But that feels redundant. What I want to be able to do is:

```
implicit val v = 5
MyObj(List("a", "b", "c"))()
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. The system complains that I'm missing my implicit arguments, which makes sense, but is a bummer.

Is there any way that I can call the function returned from the `apply` method directly without first assigning it to a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write either

```
MyObj(List("a", "b", "c")).apply()
```

or

```
MyObj(List("a", "b", "c"))(implicitly)()
```

---

*By the way, accepting `Unit` is a little weird, usually `Unit` is returned. Maybe*

```
object MyObj {
  def apply(args: List[String])(implicit v: Int): () => Int = () => args.length + v
}
```

*looks more conventional (I guess `Int` is just for example, otherwise implicits of standard types like `Int` are not recommended either).*

---

In Dotty

```
object MyObj {
  def apply(args: List[String])(using v: Int): Unit => Int = (_: Unit) => args.length + v
}

given Int = 5

MyObj(List("a", "b", "c"))(()) // 8
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tpGE0JkWT3SuQ4ri0W9dNQ

Comment: The reason I'm using `Unit` is because I need the returned function to be a `Function1` for other parts of the program, but otherwise I agree that `() => ` is cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue in scala 2.XX and fixed in dotty.

Refer 3rd point from this ticket:

> Passing explicit arguments to implicit parameters is written like normal application. This
> clashes with elision of apply methods. For instance, if you have

> def f(implicit x: C): A => B
> then f(a) would pass the argument a to the implicit parameter and one has to write
> f.apply(a) to apply f to a regular argument.

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1260